# Hibernate doesn't create tables

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I've started to learn that stuff like Spring Roo, Hibernate, JPA and so on. I have created simple model which has to be my table in PostgreSQL (I created 'jtdb' database manually). But when I deploy the pogram (by selecting Run on Server in STS) nothing is created. I can create the table by using entityManagerFactory (or smth like that), but I heard that there's possibility to do it without the factory and using some @Autowired thing.

Here are my codes:

MyTable.java:

```
package com.db.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MyTable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="jtdb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<class>com.db.model.MyTable</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://00.00.00.000:5432/jtdb"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>

        <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
        <!-- Uncomment the following two properties for JBoss only -->
        <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false" /-->
        <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false" /-->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.db.model">
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jtdb"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

database.properties

```
database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
database.url=jdbc:postgresql://00.00.00.000:5432/jtdb
database.username=user
database.password=
```

What else do you need to diagnose my problem? I don't know what I should post here.

I have no errors or excepions (in the console that I am looking at), just:

```
// a lot of info stuff but no errors or exceptions
// ...
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
paź 05, 2012 1:23:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 11456 ms
```

Comment: Do you get any exception when launching the app/server?

Comment: No, see the end of the answer now, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never actually seen the hibernate-configuration values (like `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`) put into **persistence.xml**, but I guess it could work at least for some of them, although apparently not for all. Instead, try to define them in your `entityManagerFactory` -bean:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jtdb"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />                            
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>            
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>
```